# Изменить состав группы через адресную книгу Exchange в outlook

Tags: outlook, exchange

Exchange 2013, Outlook 2021.

Не получается изменить состав группы через адресную книгу. Тип группы: группа распределения. Область: универсальная. В самой группе являюсь владельцем, управляется тоже мной, галочка - Менеджер может изменять членов группы стоит.

Ошибка: Не удается сохранить изменения состава общей группы. Недостаточно прав доступа для выполнения операции над объектом.

Подскажите в чем может быть причина.